# How to add remotingappender programmatically in log4net

Tags: c#, log4net

When I have following xml configuration to configure log4net for remotingappender, it all works.

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="RemotingAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RemotingAppender" >
    <sink value="tcp://localhost:8085/LoggingSink" />
    <lossy value="false" />
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <onlyFixPartialEventData value="true" />
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="RemotingAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

I want to do the same thing in code. I searched a littlebit and find an example like the following. But i could not get it working.

```
        ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("logName");
        Repository.Hierarchy.Logger l = (Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)log.Logger;

        // set level
        l.Level = l.Hierarchy.LevelMap["ALL"];
        // create appander
        Appender.RemotingAppender remotingAppender = new Appender.RemotingAppender();
        remotingAppender.Name = "custom";
        remotingAppender.Sink = "tcp://localhost:8085/LoggingSink";
        remotingAppender.Lossy = false;
        remotingAppender.BufferSize = 1;
        //remotingAppender.Fix = log4net.Core.FixFlags.All;
        // create pattern
        log4net.Layout.PatternLayout layout = new log4net.Layout.PatternLayout();
        layout.ConversionPattern = "%d [%thread] %-5p %c [%a] - %m [%line] [%M]%n";
        layout.ActivateOptions();

        remotingAppender.Layout = layout;
        remotingAppender.ActivateOptions();

        // add appender
        l.AddAppender(remotingAppender);
        // perform logging (doesnt work)
        log.Warn("my warning");
        log.Error("my error");
```

What is the missing side in my code?

Comment: Where can we view the logged messages? In other words when you open a file you can view the displayed logged messages, but here how can we do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get it working. i firstly load and xml configuration which is almost emptpy. Then i put the pattern layout which has same pattern string as remoting listener. My modified xml file is below:

```
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

And i load this configuration at the beginning of my application (program.c)

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

try one of `log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(...)` oveloads.

Comment: i tried adding **log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(remotingAppender);** line after creating remotingAppender object. But it still doesnt work. I can not understand why it doesnt work. i just get stuck here!

Comment: With console appender it works for me. I can't test the remoting one. Sorry.

Comment: i tried the same code with **FileAppender**. i just created a file appender and added it to Appenders. When i run my application, it created the logfile but there is no log messages in it. So i suspect that appenders are created but logs are not sent. Do you have any idea?

Comment: No idea. The simplest program that works, I can think of. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20031812/Program.cs Try reduce your code at that direction.